# Does it matter whether to give a sooner or later date when asked to suggest an interview time?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, recruitment

I received an email on Thursday 5:30 PM from someone in the recruitment team of a company I applied for, she asked me whether I'll be available for a phone interview the next day or next week, I replied by saying I'm free on Monday and I can take the call anytime on that day, it was 1 PM the next day and she didn't get back to me, so I emailed her saying if she'll be confirming a time for Monday, she replied by thanking me for my e-mail and setting a time for 10:30 AM Monday. I have two questions:

1. Does it matter whether to give a sooner or later date when asked to suggest an interview time, i.e. would it have been an added value if I had said I'm available the next day rather than Monday?
2. Was it right that I sent her my e-mail at the time I did asking her to confirm the time? Or should have I left her to get back to me?

Comment: FWIW I'd always go for the sooner time.  Regarding the extra email, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so it would have been a plus from the interviewer perspective had I suggested the next day

Comment: It probably doesn't matter for an individual interview, but consider how it will affect your overall job search if you always take the "next week" option for all interviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I send you an email that says "are you free tomorrow?" and you are not, so you say "no, but I am next week" I may or may not be ok with that. But if I ask "are you free tomorrow or next week" and you say "I am free Monday" that is just fine. If Monday wasn't an option for me I wouldn't have mentioned it. Sometimes I might notice that someone is VERY enthusiastic and can meet RIGHT AWAY but that's not always a positive. Most people have reasonably full lives (work, classes, other interviews, ...) so while I would never suggest lying and claiming to be busy, don't ever feel bad that you're not available on the earlier of two offered dates. At least you have things to do and weren't desperately waiting for me to offer you an interview.

My guess is your recruiter sent out a lot of mails and got a lot of responses, and was working on scheduling all the Friday ones and sending confirmations before getting to the Monday ones. Your email asking for confirmation wasn't rude, and it doesn't sound like she felt it was either. Relax and enjoy your interview.